# Spring Boot framework need Spring security Management Console

Tags: spring, spring-boot, grails, spring-security

I am looking for something similar to https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/latest/
for **spring boot application** to manage security roles privileges and users.

Please Note its a spring boot application not grails Application to use the above-provided dependency.

Comment: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/10/13/okta-groups-spring-security ->an external website that is providing but it looks like I need to go and register on their domain which I don't want to do.

Comment: You can change your project to compile groovy and package it (https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-java-applications) then just use the plugin source code in your project https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui

Comment: "You can change your project to compile groovy and package then just use the plugin source code in your project" - @HithamS.AlQadheeb I do not think that is going to work.  That plugin relies on Grails infrastructure.  For example, the views are implemented as GSPs.

Comment: Just re-write the views.  I could not find something ready.  You can code it in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dvelopp/SpringAngularApp

https://github.com/chris1213/User-Management-System

https://github.com/sveri/spring-boot-template

or you can check https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=spring+boot+user+management&s=stars&type=Repositories

There is no exact match but these are good start for one.